Nature vs Nurture tag naming
We're going to need a tag for the Nature vs Nurture debate; even if that phrasing is oversimplistic, it's the way the discussion is classically framed. 
I've applied the nature-nurture tag to this question but I'm not sure how it should be worded. Perhaps nature-vs-nurture would be more clear. 
What do we name this tag?

I think framing a question as nature vs nurture is setting a confrontational tone to the question. 
I understand that nature-vs-nurture is a format most people will grasp immediately, but on a site devoted to research nature-nurture sounds more practical and does not support a false dichotomy. 

How does the 'vs' make you assume one over the other? And as far as I understood the tag, it was meant to reflect a debate?

Am not saying it makes anyone assume one over the other. Just that it makes people assume one or the other and not x% this y% that. I would call that the difference between debate and discussion. And would rather have a discussion than a debate..

Agreed, thanks for explaining! +1

@Ben Brocka: thanks for the edit. This i definitely a better version of my answer

I vote nature-vs-nurture
I think this is better because it's clear it's a question of "which one of these applies here" as opposed to nature-nurture which says to me "This question is about Nature and Nurture"

I think framing a question as nature vs nurture is setting a debate like tone to the question.. I understand, that(nature vs nurture)'s  the format most people will grasp immediately, but on a site devoted to research nature-nurture tag sounds more practical(i.e: doesn't assume one or other hypothesis).

Good thoughts @AnandJeyahar. If you post that as an answer others can vote on it to decide which tag should be used.
